# Is it possible to transfer a Heroku add-on between apps?

Tags: heroku

I have 2 apps hosted on Heroku.  I'd like to transfer an add-on (cloudinary) from one app A to app B.  Is this possible? I know I can make api calls in app B using the supplied credentials from app A, but I'd like for the add-on to show up in app B's resources page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible on Heroku.

Comment: I did get word from the add-on provider (cloudinary) that they could make the switch on their end.  For anyone else in this situation, I'd recommend contacting the add-on company directly to see what they can do for you.